# Jenkins Pipeline Library and client module

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I just got started on a Jenkins pipeline school assignment. The pipeline structure resides in a library and there is a client module that refers to it, in its Jenkinsfile.
Is it possible to delegate execution to a class in the client module without invoking a script using env (sh or cmd).
I want to invoke a class directly. Does Jenkins maintain classloader isolation b/n library and external module?
Does it explode both client and lib in a common workspace and then load them together?
Or
Can I load a class lazily at runtime? Say, the pipeline in the library knows the client class (startup param or script invocation) and then instantiates it and transfers control to it? Something like an SPI.

App design:

1. Library ABC with src/vars/resources.
2. Module X uses @Library('ABC') -Jenkinsfile invokes pipeline in the Library ABC.

   Module X structure 
   src/
   package/class1

   I am trying to use the GroovyClassLoader to load a groovy src file for class1 in Library script and invoke it. The Jenkins pipeline however, does not permit GroovyClassLoader in the script. How do I whitelist it?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough to provide an answer. Could you please add a sample code snippet as to what you would like achieve and the directory structure of the library ?

Comment: Hi @Ram Kamath, I edited the original post and added more details.

Comment: The module you are referring to is a project with a Jenkinsfile and uses the shared Jenkins library `ABC` is that correct? What is that Library `X` that you are referring to here? Is it different from `ABC` ?

Comment: Sorry, the formatting was off, I tried to fix it again. There is one library, ABC and one invoking module, X.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your Jenkins shared library has the following structure.

```
ABC
|
|----src/
|----resorces/
|----var/
```

You can create a `Test.groovy` file under `src`

```
package com.jenkins
class Test {
  def execute(def dsl){
    dsl.echo "I am inside the Test class"
    println("I am also inside the Test class")
  }
}
```

Create a `pipeline.groovy` under `var` directory.

An example `pipeline.groovy` will be

```
import com.jenkins.Test
def call(final Map parameters = [:]) {
    node('master'){
       Test.execute(this) //This utilizes the class that you have defined. I
    }
}
```

Now the module can have a Jenkins file with the following content.

```
@Library('ABC')_

pipeline  // This invokes pipeline.groovy
```

Comment: This is quite simple. I want to maintain a very generic library, I want the pipeline to invoke a class (not a sandboxed script) in the module as I mentioned in the original post. My idea is to simply have all execution logic in the module, X. The module logic gets invoked in a well-defined pipeline stage. e.g. I can invoke a module script through the pipeline, sh "abc.groovy" or GroovyClassLoader - instance.parseClass(file in module).

Comment: Unfortunately, your statements are ambiguous. It will be easy to provide the answer if you could provide a directory/project structure along with a piece of code that has a problem.  Here is community guidelines that could help you to rephrase the question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think I stated my idea quite clearly in the original post. There is a module, X and a library, ABC. <br/> I am trying to dynamically invoke a class in the module X as mentioned in the OP from a script in library, ABC. The flow is Pipeline->Library ABC script -->Module X class. I am afraid I cannot make it simpler than this.